# Módulos spring boot via maven não interagem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data, spring-jpa

Estou usando Spring Boot para criar um web service RESTFul e um SOAP,  cada um em um módulo mas ambos em um único projeto. Então, eu decidi separar minha camada de domínio em um terceiro módulo já que é a mesma para ambos os tipos de web services e assim poderia reutilizar. Mesmo com a dependência entre os  pacotes no Maven, quando vou executar a aplicação, ele questiona que, por exemplo, `PessoaRepository`, que é do módulo domínio e está sendo injetada via `@Autowired` no resource `PessoaResource` do módulo restful, não pôde ser injetada por não ser um `Bean` reconhecido pelo Spring:

```
Field pessoaRepository in br.com.tassioauad.restful.resource.PessoaResource required a bean of type 'br.com.tassioauad.domain.repository.PessoaRepository' that could not be found.
```

Minha separação ficou assim:

## Módulo Domínio

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>br.com.tassioauad</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>domain</name>
        <description>Camada de Domínio</description>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </project>
```

**PessoaRepository.java**

```
public interface PessoaRepository extends CrudRepository<Pessoa, Integer>{

    //....

}
```

## Módulo RESTFul

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.tassioauad</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>restful</name>
    <description>RESTFul API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.tassioauad</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**PessoaResource.java**

```
import br.com.tassioauad.domain.repository.PessoaRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pessoa")
public class PessoaResource {

    @Autowired
    PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    //...
}
```

O que está faltando para que o `Repository` de um módulo seja reconhecido em outro módulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso geralmente acontece quando se separa o projeto em vários módulos. Acaba que o Spring não consegue realizar o *scan* dos componentes, entidades, repositorios e serviços de um módulo para outro em certas situações. Por isso, é importante informar o caminho básico de onde se encontram para que ele realize o *scan*. No caso, estamos lidando com repositórios JPA, então, vamos colocar a annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories` na classe que contém o método main:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.tassioauad.domain")
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Isso ainda não vai solucionar tudo, surgirá um erro afirmando a respeito de não ter encontrado a entidade Pessoa. Isso porque ele só se tornou capaz de fazer *scan* nos repositórios JPA, mas não nas `@Entity`. Para isso vamos adicionar outra `anottation` e agora sim tudo ficará OK:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.tassioauad.domain")
@EntityScan("br.com.tassioauad.domain")
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tive um problema semelhante a este, com solução semelhante. Eu coloquei `@ComponentScan` na minha solução, ele não estava achando uma dependência minha anotada com `@Component`

Comment: Acredito que o Spring não vá fazer scan de componentes em dependencias, pois seria muito custoso. Imagina se ele fizesse isso em cada dependencia pra descobrir se por acaso existe algum componente... Só agora pensei nisso.

Comment: Dentro do próprio projeto até é muito viável e necessário um scan automático, porque com total certeza haverá componentes ali. Nunca tinha lidado com isso em módulos separados.

Comment: Eu normalmente separo um único pacote com as coisas que o Spring precisa olhar nas dependências e aponto o `Scan` para lá também. Isso poupa o tempo dele. Tem me servido bem assim. Já foram alguns projetos e 2 dependências assim com sucesso

Comment: Excelente comentário, @JeffersonQuesado. Fica aí registrado essa dica. Farei uns testes nesse modelo!